# Dynamic primefaces menuItem don't fire command

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menu

**Environment:**

- Java 7
- Jboss 5.2
- Primefaces 6.2

The problem I get is that when I click on the menu item the command does not fire the themeSwitcherBean.changeToOld method. What is wrong?

```
MenuModel menu = new DefaultMenuModel();
```

**Create Menu**

```
...
for (Iterator<Menu> it = children.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Menu subMenu = (Menu) it.next();

    String index = subMenu.getCodi();
    String element = rootCodi + index;

    DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem(menuName);

    menuItem.setId(element);

    menuItem.setUrl(subMenu.getServletPath());
        menuItem.setCommand("#{themeSwitcherBean.changeToNew}");
    menuItem.setUpdate(":content");

    rootNode.addElement(menuItem);

}

menu.addElement(rootNode);
...
```

**Menu.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="frmMenu">
    <pu:menu model="#{sessionBean.menu}">
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set an URL to a `menuItem.url` property it is [rendered as a simple hyperlink using href](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b37306a7b953d4243015938a9a370ed70e6134f3/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/menu/BaseMenuRenderer.java#L171).
Clicking on this results in the browser to navigate to the given URL and request it using  `GET` rather than doing a `POST` request optionally using AJAX.
This finally will not update ":content" the AJAX way and not invoke your `themeSwitcherBean.changeToNew` action method.

In order to have your action method invoke you have to **skip that line**:

```
menuItem.setUrl(subMenu.getServletPath());
```

If you find you need to reload the entire page (which is likely when switching themes) instead of the element referenced using ":content" only, make your action method return that instruction as `String`:

```
public String changeToNew() {
    // do something ...
    // ...
    String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
    return viewId + "?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
```

In this case you can disable AJAX on that menu item reducing the request/response/javaScript overhead a little bit:

```
menuItem.setAjax(false);
```

Comment: Nicely explained. Better than the primefaces documentation that it doesn't say that when url is used command is skipped.